# Why am I getting a ValueError: could not convert string to float error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate a new column for a pandas dataframe which takes a column in another dataframe, uses two variables to alter the value, giving a new value. This is the current code I have to perform the calculation:

```
# Calculate the Max Stress
jac_output['Max Stress /MPa'] = (jac_input['Max Load'][::-1] + (float(load_zero))) / float(area*1000)
```

where:

```
load zero = 1.5
area = 45.345
```

However, each time I try to perform it, I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
'45.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.34545.3
```

(The 45.34534 repeats for quite a while) Why does it seem to think my area is a string? It computes the value find if I take out the `/ float(area*1000)` part, but this isn't my desired result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`area` is a string; multiplying a string causes it to repeat that number of times.

```
>>> area = "45.345"
>>> area * 5
'45.34545.34545.34545.34545.345'
```

What you want to do is convert it to a `float` and *then* multiply it:

```
>>> float(area) * 1000
45345.0
```